# Object requires array of (A, b) while client has array of class with elements (A, b)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a solver object.  The algorithm which it's intended to carry out is approximately:

- Accept inputs describing the system Ax = b.
- Solve for x using a least-squares approach (the system is over-determined for the cases considered)
- Calculate b' = Ax, the b which would be expected given the least-squares x
- Return b'

Some other constraints

- The client stores the elements of A in a compressed form (described by 2 elements `ay` and `az`), but they need to be expanded to a full 50 elements for the matrix calculations. It therefore is not a waste of memory for the solver object to have an internal A array (holding the expanded form)
- The client code to stores `ay`, `az`, and `b` as elements of an object `foo`, and thus has one array of `foo`s rather than several arrays holding `ay`, `az`, and `b`. This architecture is non-negotiable, which means:

  - I can't make a simple function `doEverything(double *ay, double *az, double *b)`
  - It's necessary for the solver object to have an internal b array (for feeding to matrix math functions – the disparate `foo::b` elements aren't acceptable for that)

The class I currently have requires proper use of the following public functions:

- `void prepForInputWith(int nElements)` – resizes internal arrays to allow space for nElements (called once)

  - The class is smart enough to re-size itself if this function isn't called, but calling this saves the trouble of reallocating every time a new element is added
- `void setAandB(double ay, double az, double b)` – sets the next row of data in A and b (called once per data point)
- `void calculateXBestFit()` – inverts the system for x (called once)
- `double returnBPrime()` – returns the answer for the next cell (called once per data point, and must be called in the same order as setNextResult was)

Note that the client must call `returnBPrime()` in the same order as `setAandB()` was called because the entries of A (which were calculated in `setAandB()` and used in `calculateXBestFit()` ) are re-used when calculating b'=Ax in `returnBPrime()`. Removing this optimization would make it possible for `returnBPrime()` to be called in any order, but would come with a runtime penalty.

I'm unhappy with this because:

- The client code seems more complicated than it needs to be
- A few things which could be taken for granted in the `doEverything()` approach can't in this approach:

  - `returnBPrime()` could be called before any answers have been calculated
  - `returnBPrime()` could be called a different number of times than `setAandB()`

  This means

  - The class needs to check whether it's being used properly, complicating the object code
  - All the checks must be performed at runtime, whereas it seems like there should be enough information to establish whether the class is being used properly at compile time

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the interface specification for this class places some constraints on the order in which clients of the class may call its functions (if they expect to get valid results). I can't think of any way to enforce that sequence at compile time.

What you can do is not access data that are out of bounds.  You clearly need some kind of internal counter to say which element of each array is modified or returned by `setAandB()`
and `returnBPrime()`. In fact I would make each of these functions use a different counter,
and I would make `calculateXBestFit()` set both of those counters to zero.
Then the next `nElements` calls to `returnBPrime()` will return the elements of b' in sequence, and you can call `setAandB()` another `nElements` to prepare for the next call
to `calculateXBestFit()`.

There are a few useful runtime checks but I think they're fairly low-cost. The main one
is to range-check the counter used by `returnBPrime()`.  Once it reaches the length of the data stored in b', subsequent calls won't attempt to read b' (but might generate an exception or error message if you can get agreement on that) until after the next call to `calculateXBestFit()`.  As long as the clients of this class hold to the contract, the cost of this runtime check is just the cost of a branch on a condition of the form `if (counter < limit)`.

There's a run-time check on `setAandB()` as well, but I think you already contemplated one (since you say the class will re-size the arrays itself if it needs to).

You need to get agreement on what happens if  `calculateXBestFit()` is called before all `nElements` elements of each array have been set by `setAandB()`.  It seems to me the best behavior is to treat the number of calls to `setAandB()` as the desired size of the arrays, regardless of what value was given for `nElements`.  This also means remembering the size of the arrays used by `calculateXBestFit()` so that `returnBPrime()` will use that number, not `nElements`, as the number of values it will actually allow to be read from b'.

By the way, I would also make `calculateXBestFit()` compute and store the contents of b' in yet another array in this object.  That means that anything that happens to the object after this call--other than another call to `calculateXBestFit()`--is not going to affect the results of the calls to `returnBPrime()`.

Let's see: that covers calling `setAandB()` too many times, calling `setAandB()` too few times, calling `returnBPrime()` too many times, and even interleaving the calls to `returnBPrime()` with the calls to `setAandB()` for the next problem to be solved. About the only remaining obvious error I can think of is calling `returnBPrime()` too few times, and the result of that is just that the client will have gotten less data than should have been the case.  And I see only one run-time check that you hadn't already committed to.